# sns clustermap order sample name in the axis

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn, heatmap

I would like to plot a clustered heatmap. However, despite the order given in the dataframe (S3_Day90_P3,S3_Day60_P3 ,S3_Day0_P1, S3_Day60_P1,S2_Day0_P2,S1_Day60_P3,S2_Day30_P3,...), it does not follow the order of the dataframe when i generate clustered heatmap.Below is a small subset of how my dataframe look

```
                          S3_Day90_P3  S3_Day60_P3  S3_Day0_P1  S3_Day60_P1  
sscinames                                                                     
Acidobacteria bacterium            17           26           0           17   
Thermoplasmata archaeon             4            0          41            1   
Planctomycetes bacterium            5            3           0            1
```

Im new to python and have been trying to read around but the code below does not give me the desired output. Any help will be appreciated.

```
df= pd.read_csv('top25_edit.csv', sep='\t')

df = df.set_index(['sscinames'])


df['sscinames']=pd.categorical(df['sscinames'],['S3_Day90_P3','S3_Day60_P3','S3_Day0_P1','S3_Day60_P1'])
df.sort_values("scinames")

sns.clustermap(df,xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't control the displayed order because `clustermap` is a hierarchical (binary) tree representation of your matrix. This is a top-down organizational structure. If you could force the order, the branches of the tree would cross and the graphs would mean nothing.

```
>>> df
                          S3_Day90_P3  S3_Day60_P3  S3_Day0_P1  S3_Day60_P1
sscinames                                                                  
Acidobacteria bacterium            17           26           0           17
Thermoplasmata archaeon             4            0          41            1
Planctomycetes bacterium            5            3           0            1
```

[image]

The order of this graph can be explained:

1. The first cell (first row, first column) is (Thermoplasmata archaeon, S3_Day0_P1) because 41 is the highest value of your matrix.
2. The second cell (second row, second column) is (Acidobacteria bacterium, S3_Day60_P3) because 26 is the highest value (excluded the row/col of 41).
3. The third cell (third row, third column) is (Acidobacteria bacterium, S3_Day90_P3) because 5 is the highest value of the remaining rows/cols.

I think the order can be naively determined by:

```
>>> df.agg(['idxmax', 'max'], axis=1).sort_values('max', ascending=False)

                               idxmax max
sscinames                                
Thermoplasmata archaeon    S3_Day0_P1  41
Acidobacteria bacterium   S3_Day60_P3  26
Planctomycetes bacterium  S3_Day90_P3   5
```